# adding table in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2015

When I add a new table in a service-based database in visual studio 2010, I just save it and the new table pops up under the tables folder in the mdf.

Now, I'm new to using visual studio 2015. I'm trying to add a new table in visual studio 2015, and when I add a new table and save it, it pops a file dialog prompting me to save it somewhere, which is not the case in visual studio 2010 whenever I save it.

or maybe I did something wrong?

[image]

Comment: What object do you want to achieve? No database project?

Comment: uhm. A table? I'm trying to add a table. Usually when I save the table (in vs2010), the table is added under the Tables folder. But when I try to save the table I made, it prompts me to save it (see image). When I save it, it does not show under the Tables under the Server Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

There is an UPDATE button just above the fields you have created.  Click on UPDATE and after that you need to click on UPDATE TABLE.

Answer (score 0):

Click 'Update' just above the table. Then in the 'Preview Database Updates' window that opens, click 'Update Database'. Then in Server Explorer, right-click on Tables folder in the database and click refresh. The table should then appear in this folder.